# Getting error while using if else

Tags: shell-script

```
if [[ wc[$clientID] != 5 ]];
then
    print "Client id entered is incorrect"

else
    print "\n" 
    print "1. QA "  
    print "2. QC " 
fi
```

ERROR

```
./ERMS.sh[16]: syntax error at line 64 : `newline or ;' unexpected
```

Comment: What is the content of $clientID and what is the output you expect?

Comment: what's `wc[$clientID]` ?

Comment: Please show a minimal script, with the error. This is not the script that produced the error-message.

Comment: What shell are you executing this piece of code with.  Is `wc` an array?

Comment: no ....actually i want a code which helps me to count the word of client id...if the client id is not of 5 digits it should execute the if part and if it's not then it should give me the else part

Answer (score 3):

According to [comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/498835/getting-error-while-using-if-else#comment918413_498835), you are expecting `wc[$clientID]` to count the number of characters in `$clientID`.  This is not what this does.

Instead:

```
if [ "${#clientID}" -ne 5 ]; then
    # denied
else
    # ok
fi
```

The `${#variable}` expansion will return an integer which is the length of `"$variable"`.  With `-ne 5` we test for arithmetic inequality with 5.

If you want to test *specifically* for five digits:

```
case $clientID in
    [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])
        # ok
        ;;
     *)
        # denied
esac
```

With the `bash` shell and its regular expression matching:

```
if [[ "$clientID" =~ ^[0-9]{5}$ ]]; then
    # ok
else
    # denied
fi
```

Using the `expr` utility (in any `sh`-like shell):

```
if expr "$clientID" : '^[0-9]\{5\}$' >/dev/null; then
    # ok
else
    # denied
fi
```

Comment: thanks..the information was very helpful..